# Which is better: Several SQL queries or one sql data with lots of data?

Tags: sql

I am making a quiz and I am expecting a lot of players for it. The quiz has a fixed number of questions.The quiz system can either fetch individual questions one by one from the MySql database and display it to the user. Or alternatively  I can fetch all the questions when he/she logs in and display them one by one. Can the second method significantly help in reducing the load on the server due to large number of SQL queries? Here I am talking about 500-600 users simultaneously playing the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to know for sure is to benchmark both methods.

For what it's worth, I've recently improved the throughput of a performance-critical piece of code ten-fold by replacing a large number of small SQL queries with a small number of large queries.

Answer (score 0):

A well indexed database should have no problems at all with single queries, which is what I would prefer. Bonus: those small queries will remain in the server's query cache and thus be delivered way faster if requested again.

Comment: I am using PHP and so thinking of storing the questions in the SESSION variables. What is the query cache that you are talking about? I'm sorry, but I am a self taught programmer and so ignorant of technical jargon.

Comment: Sorry. The "query cache" I was refering to is an internal mechanism of the MySQL server. Questions (i.e. queries) that are asked a lot get cached.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the numbers. Are you displaying all the questions or you are picking random 5 out of 1000?

If the number of questions is small, fetching them in a single query will be better.

If the number of questions is large, fetching them in a single query may use a lot of memory, so fetching them one-by-one will be better.

Comment: Its just 15 queries and no, they'll not be fetched randomly.

Comment: Then definitely, fetching them in a single query will be better. Usually the database has to analyze each query, prepare the execution plan and so on, thus it's better for the database to do it once instead of 15 times.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of questions is small, it would make little difference either way. And if the number of questions is large, fetching in a single query is more efficient since you'll avoid most of the back-and-forth network latencies.

Answer (score 0):

Except 15 *select* queries each user's answer is a individual *insert* query. Maximum advantage for DB server is 2 batches of queries: 1 select and 1 insert for every user.

In theory you may receive 500-600 inserts per second. In practice there will be less inserts.

Anyway you should avoid large number of queries cause there are overheads for insert locks.